# WordPress Search On Localhost Does Not Work

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering firstly why search functionality for WordPress does not work on my local machine and secondly how it can be rectified?

If I do a search at the moment I get a '**404 Not Found**' error stating that '**The requested URL /dev/search.php was not found on this server**.'

I tried installing the Relevanssi plugin to see if this would help but again the same error is displayed.

However, having installed this plugin the admin area now displays the following message:

'**Multibyte string functions are not available. Relevanssi may not work well without them. Please install (or ask your host to install) the mbstring extension.**'

Is anyone able to confirm if this would fix my issue or whether it is a separate issue?

If this is indeed the root of the problem then how would I go about installing it on a Win 7 PC running Apache.

Thanks for all your time and help in advance.

Comment: first of all,iwould reccomand you use xampp. would resolve both your problems. about the bad path -check both your blogurl and homeurl in the options table andconfig fie..

Answer (score 0):

Try activating any one of the defaults themes provided by WordPress like: Twenty Thirteen, Twenty Twelve, or Twenty Ten and check the default search functionality by putting a search widget in the sidebar. Seems like your current theme is missing the search.php file.

About mbstring extension, you need to setup this extension from PHP pear and tweak your php.ini